# How to put $_GET value in a variable in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, get

I am having trouble retrieving and putting the user id in the url into a variable. Here is my controller that I am trying to do this with. I have read the documentation in the user guide,however I am not getting any results.

here is my url structure:

```
clci.dev/account/profile/220
```

Controller:

```
public function profile() 
    {

        $this->load->helper('date');
        $this->load->library('session');
        $session_id = $this->session->userdata('id');
        $this->load->model('account_model');
        $user = $this->account_model->user();
        $data['user'] = $user;
        $data['session_id'] = $session_id;
        //TRYING TO MAKE A VARIABLE WITHT THE $_GET VALUE
        $user_get = $this->input->get($user['id']); 
        echo $user_get;
        if($user['id'] == $session_id)
        {
            $data['profile_icon'] = 'edit';
        }
        else
        {
            $data['profile_icon'] = 'profile';
        }
        $data['main_content'] = 'account/profile';
        $this->load->view('includes/templates/profile_template', $data);


    }
```

Am I flat out doing this wrong, or are there adjustments that I need to make in my config files?

thanks in advance

Comment: Is id you are looking for in `$_GET['id']` or `$_GET[$user['id']]`?

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to add the url structure. http://www.clci.dev/account/profile/220. I am trying to get 220. Which is $user['id'];

Comment: And in which key in GET is 220? `var_dump($_GET)`

Comment: these are the results I got with the var_dump: array(0) { }

Comment: the correct way to approach this per the framework documentation is exactly as skrilled explained, you would declare the variable in your controller function.

Answer (score 2):

In codeigniter, instead of having `something.com/user.php?id=2` we use `something.com/user/2` and the way to get that 2 is using this:

```
$this->uri->segment(3)
```

for more info http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html

edit:

based on your url: clci.dev/account/profile/220 you would need `$this->uri->segment(4)`

Answer (score 2):

You would set up your controller function as follows

```
public function profile($id = false) 
{
     // example: clci.dev/account/profile/222
     // $id is now 222
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can directly get like this:

```
public function profile($user_id = 0) 
{
     //So as per your url... $user_id is 220
}
```

Comment: where is $user_id created? right there where you have it or am I supposed to declare it somewhere else?

Comment: $user_id is not created anywhere...you called this url clci.dev/account/profile/220...so the value of $user_id is url value like 220...because you called profile function of controller

Answer (score 0):

I suppose at this point that the value for $_GET['id'] is intended to be 220 so here:
To get 220, you would have to do it this way *(except the get value in question is other than 220 as shown in your url above)*

Let's say you visit: clci.dev/account/profile/220. Follow the comments for more info.

```php
public function profile() 
{
    $this->load->helper('url'); //Include this line
    $this->load->helper('date');
    $this->load->library('session');
    $session_id = $this->session->userdata('id'); //Ensure that this session is valid
    $this->load->model('account_model');
    $user = $this->account_model->user(); //(suggestion) you want to pass the id here to filter your record
    $data['user'] = $user;
    $data['session_id'] = $session_id;
    //TRYING TO MAKE A VARIABLE WITHT THE $_GET VALUE
    $user_get = $this->uri->segment(3); //Modify this line
    echo $user_get; //This should echo 220
    if($user_get == $session_id) //Modify this line also
    {
        $data['profile_icon'] = 'edit';
    }
    else
    {
        $data['profile_icon'] = 'profile';
    }
    $data['main_content'] = 'account/profile';
    $this->load->view('includes/templates/profile_template', $data);


}
```

I hope that helps your gets your started in the right track.